# extract substring from a data in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, text, substring

I need VBA coding for  the below data in a cell a(1)... a(n) ( it can be any no row of data).

**i need answer as If Description contains any of the below(inside that cell substring) in b1 it should say ok**

- POP same as in CDAX / POP differs from CDAX;
- POP same as in CDAX;
- or in case no any mention about POP
  *
- ***b.    If Description contains any of the below:**in b1 it should say ok "Check POP date"**
- POP date inserted;
- POP differs from CDAX
  Please help me

**cell a1**
In Task Subject: WTY Ext X mths / Cpk ext X mths
o   In Task Description:
   POP same as in CDAX / POP differs from CDAX, attached
   Approver’s name (your name, your mentor/supervisor/manager, etc. - depending on the offer! – please see above)
   Device warranty period in years (1, 2, 3, etc.. years)
   Comments: (if any)
**cell a2**
   POP differs from CDAX:
POP Date: 15-06-2022
   Approver’s name: Nesrine Ben Ahmed
   Device warranty period in years: 2
   Comments: If any issue please return to queue: EMA-A-EN-CRT-QUA0

**cell a3**    POP same as in CDAX
   Approver’s name: Tea  Milosvic
   Device warranty period in years: 1 year
   Comments:  multiple repair issue, our queue: <EMA--COMPCON-LVL1>

Please help me

```
Sub Find_Char()
Dim a As String, b As String, firstline As String
firstline = Left(Range("a4"), WorksheetFunction.Find(Chr(10), Range("a4")) - 1)
Range("b8") = firstline
b = InStr(UCase(Range("b8")), "pop")
a = Mid(Range("b8"), b + 4, Len(Range("b8")))
MsgBox a
End Sub
```

suppose cells contains below  it gives the POP same as in CDAX , i wanted whole line POP same as in CDAX / POP differs from CDAX  and this pop can be anyplace in the sentence .
"POP same as in CDAX / POP differs from CDAX; POP same as in CDAX; or in case no any mention about POP * these 3 if we see in any cell in b cell it should write as ok
if it sees POP date inserted;POP differs from CDAX it should write in b cell as check pop date

cell a1 In Task Description:   POP same as in CDAX / POP differs from CDAX, attached  Approver’s name (your name, your mentor/supervisor/manager, etc. - depending on the offer! – please see above)     Device warranty period in years (1, 2, 3, etc.. years)     Comments: (if any)

[image]

Comment: Somehow the formatting of your question is broken - it's hard to understand what the conditions are. Pls edit the question to make that clearer. Adding the sample data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) would make it easier to look for an answer.

Comment: You should look at the [`Like()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator. And test your input in order against a bunch of these patterns like `If YourVariable Like "*POP same as in CDAX / POP differs from CDAX;*" Then`

Comment: Ok i will try like() and see if i can figure out,looks simple ,hope i fix it thank you